# Rails 2.3.5 / MySQL key preference issue; force index

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Greetings,

I'm looking a rather "large..." table with a couple of million rows, and for simplicity sake the table looks like this

```
create table data (
   user_id int ...
   created_on datetime ...
   ...
   key (user_id),
   key (created_on)
   ...
) engine = InnoDB;
```

So, on a query... SELECT * FROM data WHERE user_id = X and created_on = Y

The query optimizer has been preferring created_on over user_id, now I can use FORCE INDEX to "force" the issue, but I don't want to have to do that for every Data.find and every other query we have (hundreds of changes).

Can I influence Rails 2.3.5 to globally use "data FORCE INDEX (user_id_index)" when possible (and no other contradictions; ie.. another FORCE index manually entered)

or

Can I change how the mysql query optimizer prefers indexes on a more manual basis?  I've looked at running analyze table data; but the query plan doesn't change.

-daniel

Comment: no primary key ? pitty to squander your one and only innodb clustered index.

Comment: @f00: also to addition: it is better in innodb if PK grows monotonously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create composite index `user_id + created_on` instead of just `user_id` and everything will be fine.

Comment: I thought of that, but the downtime for the alter table is considerable, and I don't want to do a slave/master swap just for this.

Comment: @Daniel: this is the only solution for your problem anyway. You're free to follow the correct way or trying to find some dirty hack. If you don't want to swap them - then the issue is not important for you, just forget it ;-)

Comment: Well, I was thinking there might be some dirty trick to change the collation directly... say "on Data set collation=5 where index="created_on_index", that way I could influence how query planner is built.  Not a good long term solution, but this would be good until our next scheduled downtime window.